# Proxy all Android In App purchases to Huawei AppGallery

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, huawei-iap

Is it possible to use Huawei AppGallery for All Android In App purchases instead of Google Play Store ?
Is there any way or proxy apk can do this job?
Ps: lucky patcher have it *

Comment: hi@Akrem Berrogtane, I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: I'm trying to replace all android payment by hms, I want to redirect All in_app purchase requests from google play to Huawei AppGallery, I'm trying to find a third party app can do this job.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to replace All Google Play in_app purchase requests with Huawei AppGallery,